# Get individual Data from REST Service in javascript?

Tags: rest, service, jet

i'm trying to create ComboBox populated with data that I got from REST service in javascript. I,m doing this in oracle jet.

My Json Data looks like
"items":[{"code":"000","description":"Default"},{"code":"101","description":"Jebel Ali"}}]

I want to show description values alone in combobox.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The oracle jet combo box expects the option object should have the label and value attributes.

For Eg.

```
[ {
     "value" : "000",
     "label" : "Default"
  },
  {  "value":"101",
     "label":"Jebel Ali"
  }
]
```

If you do not want to change the json you received from the rest api you can use the data provider mapping provision as below

```
//In mapfields, use "code" as key
//map "description" to "label" and "code" to "value"
var mapFields = function(item) {
  var data = item['data'];
  var mappedItem = {};
  mappedItem['data'] = {};
  mappedItem['data']['label'] = data['description'];
  mappedItem['data']['value'] = data['code'];
  mappedItem['metadata'] = {'key': data['code']};

  return mappedItem;
}; 
var dataMapping = {'mapFields': mapFields};

//create an ArrayDataProvider using 'id' as keyAttributes
var arrayDataProvider = new oj.ArrayDataProvider(dataArray, {keyAttributes: 'code'});

//create ListDataProviderView with dataMapping
this.dataProvider = new oj.ListDataProviderView(arrayDataProvider, {'dataMapping': dataMapping});
```

You can check the same in oracle jet cookbook in the below link

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=comboboxOne&demo=dataMapping

This is as per jet 5.1 version.